# Determine if HTTP resources are available on the webserver

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, glassfish-3, grizzly

I use Glassfish v3 for serving large files (glassfish is used for business logic as well - FYI) I am aware that Glassfish frontends with Grizzily web-server. I use Grizzily in synchronous mode. Meaning, if there are 100 threads only 100 downloads are allowed. Rest of the requests will be queued. However, I want to set 503 for the HTTP clients which cannot be served due to lack of worker threads (100 max).

Question

1. Should the requests be even allowed to queued when no worker threads are available
2. How do I know when the worker threads are exhausted? A manual counter?
3. where in the code (filter, servlet?) should I set the error code along with retry header data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these are container specific features. You can configure the requests queue size using the property `server.http-service.connection-pool.max-pending-count = 100`. All requests beyond 100 will be rejected.

For more information, refer here:

[Glassfish tuning keepalive requests](https://web.archive.org/web/20131213014848/http://blogs.oracle.com/binublog/entry/glassfish_tuning_http_connection_queue)

Comment: Thnx, I was looking on similar lines . Also, on rejection, my requirement is to send a HTTP 503 along with setting HTTP "Retry-After" header. Do you reckon doing this in a servlet filter?

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet 3.0 spec introduced support for asynchronous request processing, which you can leverage.
You can introduce an application based thread pool and handle long lasting tasks there, this way you'll have full control over thread pool size and take appropriate action once thread pool reaches some limit.

Comment: Asynchronous processing comes at the cost of memory, isnt it. BTW, I find your solution of application based thread pool interesting.  Is the solution applicable for sync processing as well. Can you explain more on this please?